# Using Offset for a dynamic range, Would like to include another duplicate range within formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So I was given a formula which searches for values on columns B (buy/sell), C(ticker) and D(no of shares) with a reference cell A1 which indicates 'table' height.
`=UNIQUE(FILTER(OFFSET($C$3,0,0,$A$1),ArrayFormula(IF(SUMIF(OFFSET($C$3,0,0,$A$1)&OFFSET($B$3,0,0,$A$1),OFFSET($C$3,0,0,$A$1)&"buy",OFFSET($D$3,0,0,$A$1))-SUMIF(OFFSET($C$3,0,0,$A$1)&OFFSET($B$3,0,0,$A$1),OFFSET($C$3,0,0,$A$1)&"sell",OFFSET($D$3,0,0,$A$1))>0,TRUE))))`

For my own use I needed to have a duplicate 'table' which is on column J (buy/sell), K(ticker) and L(no of shares). How do I modify the above formula to include data from this duplicate 'table' (same columns and also same height)?

| action | ticker | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| buy | AAPL | 10 |
| buy | MSFT | 5 |
| sell | AAPL | 10 |
| buy | SPY | 6 |

Which will then display MSFT and SPY in an output table since I have fully exited AAPL.

But because I want to line them up side by side because I want to calculate other column data (not evaluated by the formula above) I need the 'pairs' line up within the row.

| action | ticker | units | action | ticker | units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| buy | AAPL | 10 | sell | AAPL | 10 |
| buy | MSFT | 5 |  |  |  |
| buy | SPY | 6 |  |  |  |

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add some sample input data , the expected result and show what you tried.

Comment: Thank you. Currently the formula works when i stack them (all buy and sell instructions) within its original range but I want to segregate them with the new 'table'.